# Как в log4cxx логировать в файл?

Tags: c++

Установил log4cxx. Запустил первый пример:

```
#include <log4cplus/logger.h>
#include <log4cplus/loggingmacros.h>
#include <log4cplus/configurator.h>
#include <log4cplus/initializer.h>


int main() {
    std::cout << "start server..." << std::endl;
    log4cplus::Initializer initializer;

    log4cplus::BasicConfigurator config;
    config.configure();

    log4cplus::Logger logger = log4cplus::Logger::getInstance(
    LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("main"));
    LOG4CPLUS_WARN(logger, LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("Hello, World!"));
}
```

ПОдскажите, как мне вывод логов перенаправить в заданный фаил?

Comment: ошибочка - речь про log4cplus

Comment: похоже как-то так: `logger.addAppender(new log4cplus::FileAppender("path/to/file.log"));`. ЗЫ: исправить вопрос можно нажав серенькую кнопку [edit].